# call post method without submit button causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have a form from which I want latitude and longitude and I want want load this without submit button.

```
<form method="post" id="myform" action="" >
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='latitude'/>
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='longitude'/>
</form>
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

But it causes infinite loop and I want it on the same page so I am not giving action.

I add this function but still not working.

```
function send_data(lat, lon) {
    document.getElementById('place_lon').innerHTML = lat + ' : ' + lon;
   //     $("input[name='lattitude']").val(lat);
    //    $("input[name='longitude']").val(lon);
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j('#myform').submit(submit_myform);
   });

    function submit_myform() {
             $j.ajax({
                url: window.location.href,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $j(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json', //data type of Ajax response expected from server
                success: myform_success //callback to handle Ajax response and submit to Paypal
            });
            return false;//prevent normal browser submission, since the form is submitted in the callback
    }

    function myform_success(response) {
        //this is called whenever the ajax request returns a "200 Ok" http header
        //manipulate the form as you wish
        $("input[name='latitude']").val(lat);
        $("input[name='longitude']").val(lon);
       // $j('#lattitude').val(lat);
      //  $j('#longitude').val(lon);
        //submit the form (to the form's action attribute)
        document.forms['#myform'].submit();
    } 

}
```

Comment: When are you executing the submit?

Comment: Probably you page keeps submitting itself to itself infinitely. Try adding some condition on document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Comment: on loading my form...

Comment: which type of condition should i use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that as soon as form is loaded it submits itself, then loads again and submits etc.

Try using AJAX request to send data to the server.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: window.location.href,
  data: $('#myForm').serialize()
});
```

Comment: i tried this and add this in my code in script.i dont know much about AJAX but still i am not getting any value in $_POST["latitude"] and $_POST["longitude"]..